# How do I check if a dependency injection service was injected in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

Let's say I register a scoped service to my ASP.NET 6 web application in `Program.cs`:

```
services.AddScoped<MyRequestService>();
```

Now let's say I have some custom middleware that runs after MVC routing:

```
app.UseRouting();

app.Use(async delegate (HttpContext Context, Func<Task> Next)
{
    await Next(); // <-- here a controller gets instantiated based on MVC routing
                  //     and *MIGHT* have 'MyRequestService' injected, but 
                  //     it's *NOT GUARANTEED*

    // what do I put here to check if 'MyRequestService' was injected into the
    // controller that was chosen by MVC?
});
```

Now, after the call to `await Next()` in the middleware, I would like to check if `MyRequestService` was used by the controller that was chosen by MVC. How can I do this?

I cannot use `Context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<MyRequestService>()` since that will just instantiate the service if it isn't already instantiated. I need to check if the controller injected it, **without** inadvertently instantiating it.

Comment: I believe there is a way to determine the controller/method selected based on the route of the request.  From there you could check if that controller has that service as a parameter in the constructor via reflection.  That's a lot of work though, I'm not sure what the benefit of this would be

Comment: @Jonesopolis I used your suggestion to use reflection, but instead of using it on a controller, I just used it on Microsoft's dependency injection mechanism. See my answer below.

Comment: Why would you want this?

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Could you inform us on what problem you are trying to solve? There are very likely more efficient solutions to that problem.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to scan the DI container by reflection, I would try to use the `HttpContext` class. It has properties like `Features` and `Items`. Both are able to hold arbitrary data within the scope of the current context. Your service could for example add an entry with a specific key (e.g. a const string) into the `Items` dictionary with any data needed within the value and in your middleware you check after the return of `Next()` if the dictionary contains the specified key. If yes, your service was used.

In that case the default mechanism of ASP is used and no reflection is needed.

Comment: Even better than my solution below as it requires less work to setup.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I would do, it is not tested but I think this concept should work and it is easier to read than reflexion in my opinion:

```
// Scoped
MyRequestService {
    constructor(MyServiceMonitor monitor) {
        monitor.AddResolved(this.GetType().Name);
    }

}

// Scoped
MyServiceMonitor {
    List<string> types; 
    
    AddResolved(string type) {
        types.Add(type);    
    }
    
    
    IsResolved(string name) {
        return types.Contains(name);    
    }
}

// Check in the delegate

context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<MyServiceMonitor>().IsResolved("MyRequestService");
```

Answer (score 0):

I used reflection per Jonesopolis's suggestion in the comments, but instead of using reflection on controllers, I'm using it to get at the internal dependency injection object cache. I'm caching the *ResolvedServices* `PropertyInfo` using a `Lazy<PropertyInfo>` object. This works, but I don't like it. Hopefully ASP.NET will have a public accessor for this soon:

```
app.UseRouting();

var ResolvedServicesPropLoader = new Lazy<PropertyInfo>(delegate ()
{
    var ProviderType = Type.GetType("Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection");
    if (ProviderType == null) { throw new Exception("service caching class type could not be found"); }
    var TheProperty = ProviderType.GetProperty("ResolvedServices", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    return TheProperty ?? throw new Exception("could not find the cached services property using reflection");
});

app.Use(async delegate (HttpContext Context, Func<Task> Next)
{
    await Next();        
    var InjectedServices = (ICollection<object>?)((IDictionary?)ResolvedServicesPropLoader.Value.GetValue(Context.RequestServices))?.Values;
    if (InjectedServices == null) { throw new Exception("cached services collection is null"); }
    if (InjectedServices.Where(x => x is MyRequestService).Any())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("service was injected");
    }
});
```

Comment: Yikes. Reflection seems a bit overkill unless you are making this an integration test and not using it in production. If you create a concrete class rather than a delegate, you can simply put a null guard clause in the constructor to ensure your type gets injected `this.service = service ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(service));`. This ensures it is always non-null or you get a clear exception in a specific place. As for determining if it is the *correct* service, that seems like something that is not likely to happen if you are in control of your DI config.